# Try and Catch on an int Array not working as expceted

Tags: java, arrays, try-catch, numberformatexception

I am trying to perform try and catch on a method parameter but I not able to do it and when the program is ran it gives me the error number format error instead of executing the code in catch block

Any help is appreciated. I am a beginner to java and programming. Thank you for taking the time to read my question.

```
 public void inputCheck(int[] checkUserInput) {
            try {
                if (!(checkUserInput[1] <= 10 && checkUserInput[1] % 2 == 0)) {

                    errorMessage = "failEven";
                } else if (checkUserInput[0] < 20 || checkUserInput[0] > 80) {

                    errorMessage = "failRange";

                } else if ((checkUserInput[0] >= 20 || checkUserInput[0] <= 80)
                        && (checkUserInput[1] <= 10 && checkUserInput[1] % 2 == 0)) {
                    errorMessage = "checkpassed";
                }

            } catch (NumberFormatException e){
                System.out.println("Please enter an number");
            }

        }
```

Error message

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "e"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
        at UserInput.promptUser(UserInput.java:27)
        at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:11)
    #
```

Comment: Please add the stacktrace of the error.

Comment: The code in your try-catch doesn't seem to produce that exception at all. It doesn't call any methods. So the exception is thrown elsewhere. Pay close attention to the line number in your stack trace.

Comment: The error is not in the code you have posted. It is somewhere else.

Comment: @Arnaud 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "e"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at UserInput.promptUser(UserInput.java:27)
 at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:11)

Comment: @displayName I am trying to check if the user input an string into an integer field and if they do I want to display error message

Comment: In general, do not add information in comments. They are for advice and clarification. Add code or error messages in the question itself, properly formatted by selecting it and using the `{}` button.

Comment: From the stacktrace, you can see that the error happens in the `promptUser` method, not in `inputCheck`  .

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't throw any type of exception so catch block is not executed at all.

In simple terms, your code in try block is free from any type of run time error so your catch block is not reached at all. Catch block is only executed when your code in try block throws a exception.

Answer (score 0):

The `catch` block handling a certain type of an exception is executed only when the code in a `try` block produces an exception of this type. Thus, your code in a `catch` could be executed only if the code in a `try` block throws `NumberFormatException`, but it doesn't. You have to either explicitly throw such an exception in a `try` block or call a method that could throw it.

```java
  try {

    if (someCondition) {
       throw new NumberFormatException();
    }

  } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
      System.out.println("Invalid format" + e.getMessage());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for the try and catch block here. Also the parameter is array of int, you cannot pass string for the parameter.
You can make use of the below, the second ASCII value will be consider.

```
int arr[] = {100,'e'};
```